# Python String Templating with Case Sensitivity

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

This is a naming script that i use to name nodes in Autodesk Maya. This particular script however doesnt use anything maya specific.

I had asked a while ago how I would go about doing something like this, where a variable convention could be used, and templating came up.

So if i had a convention like this:

```
'${prefix}_${name}_${side}_${type}'
```

I could pass these arguments:

```
bind_thigh_left_joint
```

And then run them through an abbreviation dictionary (as well as a user abbreviation dictionary), check it with relevant nodes in scene file to make sure there are no duplicates, and end up with this: `bn_thigh_L_jnt`

However I wanted it so that if one of the keys has a first uppercase letter, it would make the substitute uppercase.

For example if `{$prefix}` was instead `{$Prefix}` thigh would become Thigh, or if `{$prefix}` was `{$PREFIX}` thigh would become THIGH. However if it was `{$PREfix}` thigh would still only be Thigh.

I can do this easily enough except that I have no way to detect the individual cases of the keys. For example, if the string is `'${Prefix}_${name}_${SIDE}_${type}'` How would I find what case prefix is, and if i knew that, how would i use that with this template?

Note this code isnt the exact code i have, I have ommitted a lot of other stuff that was more maya specific, this just deals with the substituting itself.

```
from string import Template
import collections

def convert(prefix, name, side, obj_type):
    user_conv = '${Prefix}_${name}_${SIDE}_${type}'
    # Assigns keys to strings to be used by the user dictionary.
    subs = {'prefix': prefix, 'name': name, 'side': side, 'type': obj_type}

    # Converts all of user convention to lowercase, and substitutes the names from subs.
    new_name = Template(user_conv.lower())
    new_name = new_name.safe_substitute(**subs)
    # Strips leading and trailing underscores, and replaces double underscores with a single
    new_name = new_name.strip('_')
    new_name = new_name.replace('__', '_')

    return new_name

print convert('bind', 'thigh', 'left', 'joint')
>> bind_thigh_left_joint
```

Edit:
Also would like to strip multiple underscores

So if I had something like:

```
'${prefix}___${name}__${side}_____${type}'
```

I would want it to come out

```
>> bind_thigh_left_joint
```

not

```
>> bind___thigh__left____joint
```

Also the last thing, I figured since a user would be inputting this, it would be more convenient not to be adding brackets and dollar signs. Would it be possible to do something like this?

```
import re
user_conv = 'PREFIX_name_Side_TYPE01'
# do all filtering, removing of underscores and special characters
templates = ['prefix', 'name', 'side', 'type']
for template in templates:
    if template in user_conv.lower():
        # add bracket and dollar sign around match

>> '${PREFIX}_{name}_{Side}_${TYPE}01'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, we can use the power of OOP to make the template do what we want to. We can go ahead and extend the `string.Template` class (as suggested in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template)).

Let us first import some relevant methods/classes:

```
from string import Template, uppercase, _multimap
import collections
```

We then define a helper method for dealing with arguments passed to the `safe_substitute()` or `substitute()` method. (The meat for this method was taken from Python's `string` module source):

```
def get_mapping_from_args(*args, **kws):
    if len(args) > 1:
        raise TypeError('Too many positional arguments')
    if not args:
        mapping = kws
    elif kws:
        mapping = _multimap(kws, args[0])
    else:
        mapping = args[0]             
    return mapping
```

We then go ahead and define our extended Template class. Let us call this class `CustomRenameTemplate`. We write a helper method called `do_template_based_capitalization()`, that basically does the capitalization based on the template pattern you have provided. We make sure we override the `substitute()` and `safe_substitute()` methods to use this.

```
class CustomRenameTemplate(Template):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kws):        
        super(CustomRenameTemplate, self).__init__(*args, **kws)
        self.orig_template = self.template
        self.template = self.template.lower()    

    def do_template_based_capitalization(self, mapping):
        matches = self.pattern.findall(self.orig_template)
        for match in matches:
            keyword = match[self.pattern.groupindex['braced']-1]
            if keyword[0] in uppercase:  # First letter is CAPITALIZED
                if keyword == keyword.upper():  # Condition for full capitalization
                    mapping[keyword.lower()] = mapping[keyword.lower()].upper()
                else:  # Condition for only first letter capitalization
                    mapping[keyword.lower()] = mapping[keyword.lower()].capitalize()   

    def safe_substitute(self, *args, **kws):
        mapping = get_mapping_from_args(*args, **kws)
        self.do_template_based_capitalization(mapping)
        return super(CustomRenameTemplate, self).safe_substitute(mapping)

    def substitute(self, *args, **kws):
        mapping = get_mapping_from_args(*args, **kws)
        self.do_template_based_capitalization(mapping)
        return super(CustomRenameTemplate, self).substitute(mapping)
```

We are ready to use this class now. We go ahead and do some slight modifications to your `convert()` method to put this new class into action:

```
def convert(prefix, name, side, obj_type, user_conv='${Prefix}_${name}_${SIDE}_${type}'):
    # Let us parameterize user_conv instead of hardcoding it.
    # That makes for better testing, modularity and all that good stuff.
    # user_conv = '${Prefix}_${name}_${SIDE}_${type}'
    # Assigns keys to strings to be used by the user dictionary.
    subs = {'prefix': prefix, 'name': name, 'side': side, 'type': obj_type}

    # Converts all of user convention to lowercase, and substitutes the names from subs.
    new_name = CustomRenameTemplate(user_conv)  # Send the actual template, instead of it's lower()
    new_name = new_name.substitute(**subs)

    # Strips leading and trailing underscores, and replaces double underscores with a single
    new_name = new_name.strip('_')
    new_name = new_name.replace('__', '_')

    return new_name
```

And here's it in action:

```
>>>print convert('bind', 'thigh', 'left', 'joint')
Bind_thigh_LEFT_joint

>>>print convert('bind', 'thigh', 'left', 'joint', user_conv='${prefix}_${name}_${side}_${type}')
bind_thigh_left_joint

>>>print convert('bind', 'thigh', 'left', 'joint', user_conv='${prefix}_${NAme}_${side}_${TYPE}')
bind_Thigh_left_JOINT
```

### Update #1:

If you want to deal with multiple occurrences of the underscore `_` and possible special characters in the user convention, just add the following lines before the `return` statement of the `convert()` method:

```
new_name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9_]+', '', new_name)  # This will strip every character NOT ( NOT is denoted by the leading ^) enclosed in the []
new_name = re.sub('_+', '_', new_name)  # This will replace one or more occurrences of _ with a single _
```

*Note:*
An important thing to consider when stripping away special characters is the special characters used by Maya egs. for namespace representation `:` and for hierarchy representation `|`. I will leave it up to you to either choose to strip these away, or replace them with another character, or to not receive them in the first place. Most Maya commands that return an object name(s) have flags to control the verbosity of the name returned (i.e. egs. WITH namespace, full DAG path, or none of these).

### Update #2:

For the extended portion of your question, where you had asked:

> Also the last thing, I figured since a user would be inputting this,
>   it would be more convenient not to be adding brackets and dollar
>   signs. Would it be possible to do something like this?

Yes. In fact, to generalize that further, if you assume that the template strings will only by alpha and not alpha-numeric, you can again use `re` to pick them up from the `user_conv` and stuff them inside `${}` like so:

```
user_conv = 'PREFIX_name_Side_TYPE01'
user_conv = re.sub('[A-Za-z]+', '${\g<0>}', user_conv)

>>> print user_conv
>>> ${PREFIX}_${name}_${Side}_${TYPE}01
```

We used the power of *backreferences* here i.e. with `\g<group_number>`. Check the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/re.html#re.sub) for more information on backreferences in regular expressions.

Comment: Really clean answer. +1

Comment: Thank you @DrHaze. Your answers are great too

Comment: I had forgotten to add, how would i deal with say more than two underscores in a row. Lets say the user convention had three or four underscores in between in in a row , how would I replace them with just 1 underscore without having to keep adding cases for it? Also I had taken out the code, but this is actually in a class, and the user convention is passed through the __init__ constructor class. User conv is accessed through self.user_conv instead

Comment: Also, if i were to put the CustomRenameTemplate class in another module, do i put the def get_mapping_from_args function outside and before the class?

Comment: Alright, I got it working just fine, it passes all my various tests. Thanks! Now I just have to figure out the best way to handle extra underscores, and I should probably implement a way to filter out special characters as well that aren't a-z or underscores.

Comment: I will look into what you ve asked for about the underscores when I have access to the computer. Can you update your question with the stuff about underscores too?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the underscore and special characters stuff. I have also added an extra note to be considered. Hope it helps.

Comment: Alright thanks! Better than my solution lol. I had a while loop and did a regex that would search for 2 or more reptititions, then override the new_name variable with a string replace of the captured regex group, and would keep going until all repititions were removed. I added one more question in addition to the question about underscores. I'm having a troubling time trying to figure it out. It would be the last thing i need to complete this setup.

Comment: All this is 3 questions in one! But I ve updated my answer to answer that anyway.

Comment: Yeah, sorry i just wanted to finish this problem without having to ask more questions XD. Everything passes my tests and expectations now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For anyone wanting to use this nice answer in Python 3: replace ``uppercase`` with ``ascii_uppercase``, and ``_multimap`` with ``_ChainMap`` (from the collections module which is already imported).

Comment: This kind of code is a nightmare for maintenance: it is not a generic case-insensitive string.Template solution that works as any user would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Create duplicate substitutions for each capitalization you want to support. Loop over the key/value pairs in your original `subs` dictionary with `dict.items()` or `dict.iteritems()`. `'KEY': 'VALUE'` and `'Key': 'Value'` pairs are easy to create with `.upper()` and `.title()`.

If supporting `'KEy': 'Value'` is really important to you, that can be done by looping over indices of the key, splitting, upper-casing the first part, and re-combining. For example, if `key` is `'Hello'`,

```
key[:2].upper() + key[2:]
```

will be `'HEllo'`.

Then, just use `safe_substitute` as normal.